# What does select * from table where column * 'value'; do?

Tags: mysql, operator

```
select * from table where column * 'value';
```

I accidentally wrote * for my where statement instead of =, and the query returned all rows in the table.

Made me wonder why an error wasn't thrown instead.

What does the * operator do in a where statement?

Answer (score 2):

The SQL

```
WHERE column * value
```

is a numeric operation of multiplication, and when the value of the expression (`column * value`) isn't 0, that is equivalent to TRUE so will return the row.

Comment: Maybe you should remark this syntax is only valid for MySQL and SQLLite.

Comment: Starting with V11 this is also valid in Db2 (as long as the multiplication is valid)

Comment: In MySQL, if `column` and/or `'value'` are strings, you get a Warning " Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value:..." for each string.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM <MY_TABLE> WHERE <COL_NAME> * 1;
```

Although this syntax works for [MySQL 8.0](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b162f1b3329ed9bc092ed2a4a4b9c5a3) and [SQLite 3.8](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=ddd781889042d597d3a05133960c067b) you will get an error on mostly  all other RDBMS.

**[SQL Server 2017](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b162f1b3329ed9bc092ed2a4a4b9c5a3)**

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ';'.

**[PostgreSQL 11](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=b162f1b3329ed9bc092ed2a4a4b9c5a3)**

<sub>For integer columns:</sub>

> ERROR:  argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type integer

<sub>For text/varchar columns</sub>

> ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying * integer

**[Oracle 18c](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ddd781889042d597d3a05133960c067b)**

> ORA-00920: invalid relational operator